# Flask - SQLAlchemy - clear tables as well as many-to-many linking table

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy, cascade

I have two relations: Service and Stop. They form a many-to-many relationship with each other. 
I would like to clear all data from both tables while also emptying their many-to-many linking table.

I tried the following.

```
Service.query.delete()
Stop.query.delete()
```

This cleared both tables, however **all data in the linking table** remained untouched.

Service model:

```
class Service(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'service'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
    service_type = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
    description = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
```

Stop model:

```
class Stop(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'stop'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
    latitude = Column(Float(), nullable=False)
    longitude = Column(Float(), nullable=False)
    services = relationship("Service",
                    secondary=stop_service,
                    backref="stop")
```

Can someone please tell me how to automatically clear the linking table too, without having to loop through the "stop" table?

Answer (score 2):

Just set [`ondelete` to `CASCADE`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/constraints.html#on-update-on-delete) in your joining table (`stop_service`)'s definition:

```
stop_service = Table("stop_service", meta,
  Column("service_id", ForeignKey('Service.id', ondelete="CASCADE")),
  Column("stop_id", ForeignKey('Stop.id', ondelete="CASCADE")))
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I understand now that the deletion has to be triggered by the database, because query.delete() is a bulk operation. However, even after adding "ondelete", the linking table didn't get emptied out. I'm using an SQLite database. Here's my database schema: http://i.gyazo.com/0a8b2ea038d8291fca7dc1f7ec4a21be.png